# ArcGIS Address Locator Styles & Interpolation

Tags: arcgis-server, geocoding

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3 to build an address locator service based off an address point feature class.  I want to use the Suggest operation to return possible addresses to an end user.  However, I only want **ACTUAL** addresses from the feature class to return, not interpolated addresses that may or may not exist.

Which [ArcGIS locator styles](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/commonly-used-address-locator-styles.htm) will prevent interpolation from occurring?  Alternatively, is there a way to turn it off on any locator style?